Cannot access kibana feature
I have kibana 8.14 configured locally, and I am trying to access the visualize library page but it's blank and this error is printed in the dev console:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editApp')
I tried redo the configuration on the newest version but it gave the same error.

Ensure the 'visualize' plugin is enabled in your Kibana configuration

Hello, how can i check if it is enabled?
